# Nested field model not saving the parent association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `SaleQualifier` Model in my rails app that `has_many answers`. When trying to save both the `sale_qualifier` and the `answer` I'm getting the error `Answers sale_qualifier can't be blank` and I can't work out what the issue is, as I've got these nested attributes working in other forms on the app.

The `SaleQualifier` is shown on the `SalesOpportunity` page, so I first define this in the `SalesOpportunity show` action:

```
  def show
   @sales_opportunity = SalesOpportunity.includes(:company, :user, :timeline_events, :sale_contacts, :swots, :sale_competitors).find(params[:id])
   @sale_qualifier = SaleQualifier.new(sales_opportunity_id: params[@sales_opportunity.id])
   @answer = @sale_qualifier.answers.build
 end
```

As you can see I'm building the association in the show controller, which ought to then update via the `SaleQualifier create` action. In the SaleQualifier controller I have set the following:

```
    def sale_qualifier_params
     params.require(:sale_qualifier).permit(:question_id, :answer_id, :next_question_id, :answered, :sales_opportunity_id, answers_attributes: [:answer_text, :sale_qualifier_id])
   end
```

My Sale Qualifier code:

```
class SaleQualifier < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :answers, :inverse_of => :sale_qualifier
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity
 validates :sales_opportunity_id, presence: true
end
```

My Answer.rb:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :answer_text, presence: true
 belongs_to :sale_qualifier
 validates :sale_qualifier_id, presence: true
end
```

My view form:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <%= form_for(@sale_qualifier) do |f| %>
 <% if @sale_qualifier.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@sale_qualifier.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this answer from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @sale_qualifier.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2><%= @question.question_text %></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id %>
    </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
        <%= answer.text_area :answer_text, :placeholder => "Enter your answer" %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-success"%>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

All fields show correctly on the view. This is the log file from the submit button click:

```
Started POST "/sale_qualifiers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-13 13:12:57 +0800
Processing by SaleQualifiersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0NdiFqK9O2fqh7TvDamrUL4jeQ6otcoQGhBZX9DlaSg=", "sale_qualifier"=>{"sales_opportunity_id"=>"77", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"answer_text"=>"An Answer"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

The error returns "Answers sale_qualifier can't be blank".

I'm sure there's some straightforward error that I can't see in my code, if anyone can help me find it I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the answer comes to me shortly after posting the question on here. This was the offending line in my code:

```
validates :sale_qualifier_id, presence: true
```

Removing that lets me update the sale_qualfiier and the answer.